# Custom template message for sharing a site in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

The environment I'm building is for Requests for Proposals (RFP).

The reason for sharing my site with external Microsoft accounts is to get collaboration within the entire site collection by different agencies in different areas.

What kicks off the collaboration is when they get notified that there's a new RFP to bid on.

Since I can't force alerts on external accounts, I want it to be as apparent as possible that I need those external users to subscribe to alerts on that RFP list so they get an email when a new one is available.

I figure I'll make that apparent in as many places as possible, but from the very first interaction would be helpful.

So in the dialog for sharing invitation that gets sent to the new external user, I'd like to put in a link to subscribing to that list.

Can I edit "pendingreq.aspx" in Designer?

Any thoughts/suggestions? If I'm reinventing the wheel, please let me know.

Comment: I believe when something is shared, you can add comments.  I know it's tedious, but it's something.

Comment: @wjervis That's my work-around at this point; have a canned message to copy and paste for each invite. I'm not the user of the system so trying to avoid workarounds with too many manual steps.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to put a link in the invitation e-mail, which will confuse users. If they click the link before creating an account, they can't access the site. Both as solution and workaround, it's a bad idea.

Instead, add a description on the start page which the user will see when they sign in to your SPO Site. Allow the user to "delete" the message, when they have created the alerts (or are annoyed enough seeing the message).

Comment: Good idea! Can you get more specific on how you set it up?